# min-device-width depends on zoom in Firefox

Tags: css, media-queries

In my css I am using media queries like the following in order to define a variable --screenWidth containing the number of pixels in the width of the screen:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1856px) {:root {--screenWidth: 1856px;}}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1920px) {:root {--screenWidth: 1920px;}}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 2048px) {:root {--screenWidth: 2048px;}}
```

I have a screen which is 1920px wide. This value is always returned by the --screenWidth in Chrome whatever the zoom is, but in Firefox the value of --screenWidth depends on the zoom. For example it becomes 2048px when the zoom value is 90% and becomes 1680px when the zoom value is 110%.

How can I make the behaviour the same on both browsers ?

Comment: If that's how Firefox works then you can't change it. You can create a PR for FF since it's an open source project and hope that it get's approved. But other than that: Why would you need this behaviour at all in the first place?

Comment: I use the variable --screenWidth all over my css in order tow show content bigger or smaller depending on the screen width. This works fine. The only left problem is that in Firefox min-device-width depends on the current zoom value, this has as result the fact that zooming does not work properly in Firefox.

Comment: if you zoom you have less screen width. To be honest I think even Chrome should behave this way. What exactly is the problem, if you have less screen space because of zooming you also show different page structure? That's how most of the websites nowadays work.

Comment: In Chrome when the zoom value is 30% for example everything is smaller as expected. But in Firefox most components (based on --screenWidth variable) still have the same size (zooming out practically has no effect in FF in this case).

Comment: Can you create a fiddle in your question which demonstrates this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Firefox `-moz-document` specific media query:

```
@-moz-document and (min-device-width: 1920px) {:root {--screenWidth: 1920px;}}
```

This way you can make your page work differently depending on the browser.

Now for behaving differently according to the zoom level in Firefox I don't know if it's possible using only `min-device-width`. As it was pointed by cloned, when there's less screen space because of zooming a different page structure is expected behaviour.